# Can't able to retrieve the data using joins

Tags: php, mysql, join

I've two tables **level** & **product**, basically I need to find out **level.id = 1**, but I also need to know if it has product attached to this id
in **product** table. There is a **pdcatid** in my **product table**. Now
the query works only if this id also in **product table**,
if **product table** doesn't have this id, it will fail and retrurn empty. How can I show both situations?

- if has product, show pdcatid
- if no product, show NULL

Here is my query I've tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM level 
RIGHT JOIN product on level.`id` = product.`pdcatid` 
WHERE level.`id` = 1
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join instead of right join.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM level LEFT JOIN product on level.`id` = product.`pdcatid` WHERE level.`id` = 1
```